# ¿Por qué sale el error ErrorException: Undefined array key &quot;password&quot; al hacer attept en JWT Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo un pequeño login usando Laravel. Ya logré asegurar las rutas, solo falta validar token y crearlo, lo normal. El problema es que aún siguiendo la documentación me sale este error:

```
ErrorException: Undefined array key &quot;password&quot;
```

Mi controlador es el siguiente:

```php
public function login(Request $request){

    $jsonData = $request->json()->all();

    try{

        $user =  User::where('email',$jsonData['email'])->get(); //if exist

        $arrayUser = json_decode(json_encode($user), true);
        $credentials = $arrayUser[0];
        unset($credentials['password']); //quito pass

        //$credentials = $request->only(['Id','email','name']);

        $token = auth()->attempt($credentials); //genero token
        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Unauthorized',
            ], 401);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'ok',
            'message' => 'login',
            'user' => $token,
        ]);

    }catch(QE $exception){
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'ok',
            'message' => $exception->errorInfo,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Primero obtengo los datos del request para posteriormente verificar si existe en la base de datos, después intenté de dos formas: primero como es query regresa al usuario, le quito el campo password para generar el token sin él, la otra forma es hacer request only como en la documentación, pero en mi caso si quiero ponerle Id al token por lo que la primera opción es mi ideal.

Y como ven no se genera solo ese error, he mirado varios videos y de las formas que hay de generar token ninguna me funciona, solo tira ese error. Mi modelo User es el que genera laravel por defecto pero modificado como dice la documentación de jwt-auth.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]